# Picking a random element from an array with exceptions

Tags: arrays, random, processing

I'm trying to pick a random element from an array with exceptions.

For example let's say I have a boolean array with length 10, 2 of these are set to true at a random index. How can I select a random false boolean and set it to true?

I hope this isn't too vague, English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of ways to do this. Two main approaches that occur to me:

You could use a while loop that picked a random index until it found one that was false:

```
boolean[] array = {false, true, false};
int index = int(random(array.length));
while(array[index]){
   index = int(random(array.length));
}
```

Or you could create a new array (or ArrayList) from just the indexes that are false, then randomly pick from that array:

```
boolean[] array = {false, true, false};
ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if(!array[i]){
      indexes.add(i);
   }
}
int index = indexes.get(int(random(indexes.size())));
```

Note that you've tagged your question with the [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) tag, so I'm using Processing syntax here. But these approaches are valid in a general sense as well.

Comment: Thanks, this should help me along!